# What is the performance impact of using AsReferenceDefault =true on ProtoBuf

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm migrating from the DataContractSerializer in favor of ProtoBuf. One thing that we did previously noticed is that there was a huge impact by using the `IsReference =true` of the DataContract with the XML serializer.

I would like to know if there is some reference somewhere about what happens we use the the `AsReferenceDefault = true` of the `ProtoContract`.

What are the impact on the speed of serialization/deserialization? What are the impacts on what is serialized?

Side question: Is it mandatory that all reference to one object have the IsReference = true, or can I have the main one(the one that really own the object, the place I would expect to have the object serialized) with a IsReference = false and still have only one instance of the same object?

Answer (score 1):

This flag changes a number of things:

- when serializing, it means that for every object marked in this way, it needs to check a reference lookup to see if it has already seen it; this shouldn't be *particularly* slow, but it is extra work that needs to happen
- it then needs to write an extra layer of abstraction - essentially a wrapper object that includes either the pre-existing object id, or the new object id plus the object payload (this is shaped as a `NetObjectProxy` from [bcl.proto](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/Tools/bcl.proto), for the curious - with field `1` (existing object), or fields `2` and `10` (new objects) set); this will also take a little space per reference (but less space than serializing the object repeatedly)
- this extra layer is slightly awkward (but not impossible) for other implementations to consume; essentially the core protobuf APIs have no concept of object identity, so this is a library-specific addition; if you're just using protobuf-net you should be fine

As for how that adds up in reality: it will depend on the scenario, and I'd love to hear your findings.

Re where you need `AsReference`: if it isn't specified via `AsReferenceDefault`, it will need to be specified on all members *where you expect reference tracking to occur*. The check is applied at the individual member level, essentially of the form (although this isn't the actual code):

```
bool asRef = member.AsReferenceSpecified()
    ? member.AsReference : metaType.AsReferenceDefault;
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try to test(not sure how to see the difference). Is there a way to specify the AsReference for the whole serializer? Also, I've the feeling that no matter the root node is marked as `AsReferenceDefault`, it will never be serialized accordingly. According to my test, it's always a different reference. Is this the expected behavior?